# how to change android : layout_centerHorizontal = "true" to "false" at runtime

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I would like to know how to change layout_centerHorizontal of my FrameLayout dynamically .

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You may need RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following sample code to change the attribute **for View in RelativeLayout**,

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) myFrameLayout.getLayoutParams();//get old parameters
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);//change parameter
    myFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);//set new parameters
```

[Click to learn more about RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int))

Answer (score 2):

The android:layout_centerHorizontal is for parent layout, that mean its parent must be RelativeLayout not itself. 
And the following sample code be fine for me(represented as RelativeLayout.TRUE for true or 0 for false):

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = (LayoutParams) mTextView.getLayoutParams();
    rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    mTextView.setLayoutParams(rl);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work ! Apparently, I can't vote before 15 of reputation but thx.